# In Vim, how to match pattern only if it occurs once?

Tags: regex, vim

I have the following text :

```
Line 1 : orange blackberry orange coconut
Line 2 : orange
Line 3 : blackberry coconut blackberry
Line 4 : pear orange apricot
```

I want to find the lines where "orange" occurs only once, i.e. lines 2 and 4 (for "blackberry", it would be line 1 only).

I tried a negative lookahead construct (orange NOT FOLLOWED BY orange) but failed miserably…

```
/orange\(.*orange\)\@!
```

gave me line 2 and 4 but also, as I should have foreseen,  the second instance of orange in line 1.

How should I proceed ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
/\(orange.*\)\@<!orange\(.*orange\)\@!
```

where

- `\(orange.*\)\@<!` - a negative "lookbehind" that makes sure there is no `orange` anywhere before the current position on the line
- `orange` - an `orange` substring
- `\(.*orange\)\@!` - a negative "lookahead" that makes sure there is no `orange` anywhere after the current position on the line.

Very magic mode notation:

```
/\v(orange.*)@<!orange(.*orange)@!
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much both for the answer and for the explanation (I did not know one could make a construct with the two lookarounds at the same time). Thanks again.